# jQueryUI: dialog() title bar not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/590hbj9y/5/

Clicking the different buttons generates a different dialog body, but the dialog title is unchanged. How can I get the title to change?

Here's the code from the fiddle. (Would be nice if StackOverflow wrote an automatic importer for this!)

HTML

```
<section id="dialog" title="hi">Hello</section>
<input type="button" msg="Sup" value="Say Sup">
<input type="button" msg="Yo" value="Say Yo">
<input type="button" msg="Foo" value="Say Foo">
```

JS

```
function showMessage(evt) {
    var msg = $(evt.target).attr('msg');
    var dialog = $("#dialog");
    dialog.attr('title', "Showing " + msg);
    dialog.text(msg);
    dialog.dialog();
}

$(function () {
    $("input").click(showMessage);
});
```

CSS

```
#dialog {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Your code at jsfiddle is changing `title` _attribute_ of the `div`, just hover over the dialog, and you'll see it ; ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the title as an option.

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-title

```js
function showMessage(evt) {
    var msg = $(evt.target).attr('msg');
    var dialog = $("#dialog");
    dialog.text(msg);
    dialog.dialog({
  title: "Showing "+ msg
 });
}

$(function () {
    $("input").click(showMessage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css"/>

<section id="dialog" title="hi">Hello</section>
<input type="button" msg="Sup" value="Say Sup">
<input type="button" msg="Yo" value="Say Yo">
<input type="button" msg="Foo" value="Say Foo">
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!